# Excel won't show list of autosaved documents even though I've set autosave to every minute

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've just lost quite a lot of work.

I hit save every few minutes myself just to be extra careful but even when I reopened the document, it opened to a far earlier version that excludes much work I've done.

I went to the autosave folder, unless I'm going to the incorrect folder, there's only one unrelated autosaved Excel spreadsheet.

If I've set it to save every 1 min, should there not be a vast collection of files stored?

I'm working on a Mac / Mavericks OS

Also, I can see the Sandwich Baron (Version 1) when I try save a blank document to the autosave folder but when I go there, there's no Sandwich Baron (Version 1)

Any answer will be MUCH appreciated!!!

Comment: just to clarify, you are clicking Save, not Save As...,   correct? any chance that you are reopening the wrong document? That might explain why your changes are disappearing. Also, don't expect to have lots of backup files. MS auto-save temp documents automatically delete themselves when excel closes gracefully (or they do in windows). Autosave is about preserving changes in case of application crashes and power failures, not as a kind of versioning system, so if excel exits without crashing, all the temp files are deleted.

Comment: So to clarify, there's an autosave that shows itself in the autosave folder when I am in the 'Save as' window, saving a blank document. When I go to the actual folder, all the same documents are there except the one that I am seeing in the 'Save as'. It's like it's hidden.

Comment: In windows at least, MS Office temp save files are hidden (via the 'h' file attribute)by default, so that seems to jive. Remember, a user should never ever interact with the temp files, unless you are doing some kind of recovery job after office or your computer crashes.